# Manipulate the keys of a Type to add prefixes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need a utility type takes any object-like type `T`, and returns a new type with all of the keys prefixed with the '$' character. For example:

```
type Base = { foo: number; bar: boolean };
type Prefixed = Dollar<Base>; // { $foo: number; $bar: boolean }
```

Mapped types are pretty new to me and I found the docs on [Template Literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), but I can't quite grasp how to map an entire type, rather than just a single property key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) and would benefit from using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types):

```
type Dollar<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as `\$${Extract<K, string>}`]: T[K]
}
```

A possible wrinkle here is that I needed to escape the `$` character in order to make my IDE happy, although I don't think it's strictly necessary. You can verify that this behaves as you expect:

```
type Prefixed = Dollar<Base>; 
/* type Prefixed = {
    $foo: number;
    $bar: boolean;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbygMwPbYFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNxTlxUHm4A2EchUAvjQFB9QkKABFsrVowA8AFQB8UVGj5RVUANoBpKAEsuAawghsmKDKiIoAAwA6AEjtoAogA9gVOAGNgUzQBooBHc9AHM5bisAXQIZLUi+bgEhaAAFKghMHRcIABNFUXFJKil4JDk6PgB6ACooZKg0jKzc-OU1KDscfCIySloVNTsGJno2DkJ+bihqyqA)

Comment: Much appreciated! Did not realize the `as` keyword did that as well. Not sure why the downvotes above!

Comment: I don't know about the downvotes either; it wasn't me anyway.